# How does this theorem in mathematical analysis prove correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Theorem** Suppose $Y\subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if $E=Y \cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

The necessity part comes the confusion:

If $E=Y \cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$, then the subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$.

The question is:

How can $E$ be open relative to $Y$ given $E=Y \cap G$ and $E=Y$ closed?

Comment: btw, how to upload the picture?

Comment: Of course to prove the theorem you need the definition of "open relative to".  Without that definition, you are stuck.  In some texts, what you wrote as "Theorem" is the definition.  What is the definition in your text?

Comment: You can refer to mathematical analysis textbooks, where they are well defined.

Comment: Is that a theorem? It seems to me like this is the definition of the subspace topology.  So I wouldn’t say that you can prove it. I’d think that what you can prove is that this definition of open sunsets of $Y$ satisfies the definition of a topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being open and being closed are not mutually exclusive properties. Every topological space is both open and closed relative to itself.

Additionally, sets are not intrinsically open or closed - it depends on the total space. For example, the unit interval $[0,1]$: every ball in $\mathbb{R}$ centered at $0$ contains some negative numbers, so $[0,1]$ is not open relative to $\mathbb{R}$. However, a ball in $[0,1]$ centered at $0$ or $1$ only contains points in $[0,1]$, so the endpoints are no longer problematic. This means that $[0,1]$ is open relative to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.